# Exported MacOS app prompts "Sign in to use this application on this computer" and "Damaged"

Tags: xcode, xcode8, archive, provisioning-profile, macos-sierra

In XCode 8.2 I have two MacOS apps under development that I will refer to as A and B.  From Organizer I am able to "Export as a macOS App" for app A and run it on another mac without error.  But when I do the exact same for app B the other mac displays a prompt "Sign in to use this application on this computer" and "B was purchased using the App Store on another computer...".  I shouldn't have to sign in, but when I do the next result is the "Damaged" error.

Both have "Automatically manage signing" selected.  I can validate both for the App Store and "Developer ID-signed".

Comment: Has a previous version of application B been uploaded to the Mac App store and might be installed on your Mac? You should not have to authenticate with your Apple ID unless the app has been downloaded from the store.

Comment: My mistake.  I have receipt validation code in B that was returning false instead of true :-).